# Python: iterating over SOME key:value pairs in a dictionary, but not the whole dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a series of dictionaries that basically all have the same keys, but different values assigned per dictionary.

For simplicity lets say I have  3 dictionaries:

```
dict_one = {
    "three letter code": "Arg:",
    "C": 1,
    "H": 2,
    "N": 3,
    "O": 4,
    "a_string": "nope",
}


dict_two = {
    "three letter code": "Doh:",
    "C": 5,
    "H": 6,
    "N": 7,
    "O": 8,
    "a_string": "nah",
}

dict_three = {
    "three letter code": "Uhg:",
    "C": 9,
    "H": 10,
    "N": 11,
    "O": 12,
    "a_string": "no",
}
```

Say I'd like to loop through each of these dictionaries and multiply the values contained in the keys `"C" and "N" and "O"` by 4. Because they are ints. We do math with ints.

I do not want to multiply `"three letter code" or "a_string"` Because they are strings, and whats the point of multiplying strings, right? (there is, just not for my case).

If you have a good way of tackling this then by all means, be my guest.

But I was thinking since all my dictionaries have key:value pairs that are in a consecutive order, I was wondering  if it is possible to loop over them the same way you could loop over a chunk/range of indices in a list. For example:

```
arr = ["zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five"]

for i in range(2, 5):
    print(arr[i])
```

doesn't loop over and print the full list, Instead it only produces an output of :

```
two
three
four
```

Would a similar method of looping be possible for a dictionary? if not, that is alright, and I appreciate the time taken to help out a biology student who doesn't know a whole lot about coding.

Comment: rather than try and isolate keys within the dictionary, why not have a sub-dictionary which contains the multipliable data? e.g. `dict_three = {
    "three letter code": "Uhg:",
    "the data": {
        "C": 9,
        "H": 10,
        "N": 11,
        "O": 12,
    },
    "a_string": "no",
}`

Comment: Can't you just do `for i in "CNO": print (dict_one.get(i), dict_two.get(i), dict_three.get(i))`?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
required_keys = list('CHNO')
for dct in (dict_one,dict_two,dict_three):
    for keys in required_keys:
        dct[keys] *= 4
```

Answer (score 2):

(Your question is a typical illustration of [The XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/):-))

You may use the `type()` function to multiply *only integer values:*

```
import pprint                        # Only for nice test print

dict_one = {
    "three letter code": "Arg:",
    "C": 1,
    "H": 2,
    "N": 3,
    "O": 4,
    "a_string": "nope",
}

for key in dict_one:
    if type(dict_one[key]) is int:
        dict_one[key] *= 4

pprint.pprint(dict_one)
```

The output:

> ```
> {'C': 4,
>  'H': 8,
>  'N': 12,
>  'O': 16,
>  'a_string': 'nope',
>  'three letter code': 'Arg:'}
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a code to do this in one of your dicts

```
for i,j in dict_three.items():    
    if(type(j) is int):
        dict_three[i]=dict_three[i]*4
```

Answer (score 1):

Dictionaries aren't in any real specific order (well, keys are in the order declared in Python 3.7+, but that's not the way to go here).

If you know which keys are integers beforehand, you can just loop over those keys, gather the values and do whatever:

```py
int_keys = ["C", "H", "N", "O"]

for d in (dict_one, dict_two, dict_three):
    int_values = [d[key] for key in int_keys]
    print(int_values)  # You can do whatever you like with these
```

If you don't know which of the keys are integers, you can interrogate the values' types:

```
for d in (dict_one, dict_two, dict_three):
    int_values = [value for value in d.values() if isinstance(value, int)]
    print(int_values)  # You can do whatever you like with these
```

Both of these output

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[5, 6, 7, 8]
[9, 10, 11, 12]
```

Answer (score 1):

One way of achieving your goal (although it doesn't take into account the key order as you specified in the question) is using a dictionary comprehension (doesn't modify the original dictionary, but returns a new one instead). Here's an example for *dict_one*:

> ```py
> >>> dict_one = {
> ...     "three letter code": "Arg:",
> ...     "C": 1,
> ...     "H": 2,
> ...     "N": 3,
> ...     "O": 4,
> ...     "a_string": "nope",
> ... }
> >>>
> >>> dict_one_processed = {k: v * 4 if isinstance(v, (int,)) else v for k, v in dict_one.items()}
> >>>
> >>> dict_one_processed
> {'three letter code': 'Arg:', 'C': 4, 'H': 8, 'N': 12, 'O': 16, 'a_string': 'nope'}
> ```